# Whats the best way to check the existence of external software in R?

Tags: r

I want my code to only execute if software exists on my machine external to R.  Let's say the external executable is called `foo`.  One way I am thinking about is:

```
if (nchar(Sys.which("foo")) > 0) {
  # my code
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: That seems pretty standard. I'm using `as.character(Sys.which('whoami')) != ''` in some of my code but that is basically the same

Comment: That looks basically fine. You may want to use `nzchar(.)` instead of `nchar(.)>0`

Comment: The only other option I can think of is looking in known, well-defined places for specific executables. This is a little more invasive and can fail in creative ways, but `Sys.glob` can help *search* for something not in `PATH` (on which `Sys.which` relies).